# HP Pavilion G6 administrator password problems

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, passwords, administrator

My Aunt passed away and I got her laptop but don't know the passwords to get into it. What can I do? Can it be factory reset without them?

Comment: You can enable the built-in Administrator and use that, hopefully, that isn't the account that your Aunt was using.  How you enable that account is well documented.

Comment: I'm super new to this.. where do I go to find how to enable it? I'm sorry lol